# WooCommerce woocommerce_check_cart_items and cart total

Tags: woocommerce, cart

When I try to get cart total in woocommerce_check_cart_items hook, I get zero instead of the actual cart total. Any idea why? Here is the code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'check_total');
function check_total() {
    echo WC()->cart->total; // this return zero
    echo WC()->cart->subtotal; // this returns fine, but without shipping costs
}
```

Comment: The get_cart_total() function returns the total cost of the products, but without tax and shipping costs.

Comment: Any idea which hook should I use? I want to prevent users from going to checkout page, if cart total is less than a value. From what I get, the woocommerce_check_cart_items hook, does exactly that, but fails to calculate the cart total.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use other code as I have used ever. and it's working fine for me every time.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'display_woocommerce_cart_totals', 10 );

function display_woocommerce_cart_totals(){
     global $woocommerce;
     echo $woocommerce->cart->total; 
     echo $woocommerce->cart->subtotal; 
}
```