# Set Max Purchase Totals in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart

I am trying to set a max purchase total in my WooCommerce cart. (Background: I want to prohibit people, who use 100% coupons in this case, to add more products to their cart.)

This is the code I adapted from [here](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/set-purchase-limits-on-woocommerce/):

```
// Weitere Einkäufe verhindern

add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'cldws_set_max_total');
function cldws_set_max_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        // Set maximum cart total
        $max_cart_total = 1;
        // A maximum of 1 € is required before checking out.

        $total = WC()->cart->totals;
        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
        if( $total >= $max_cart_total  ) {
        // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>Bitte lege nicht mehr Stränge in den Warenkorb als du beim Crowdfunding bestellt hast.</strong> Die genaue Anzahl findest du in der E-Mail mit dem Gutscheincode. '),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what it should do:

After checking that this only runs on the cart and checkout pages and setting the max. totals value to 1 €, I query the cart's totals and compare them to this max value. If the total is bigger than the max. allowed total, it displays the error message.

I suspect that I am querying the wrong variable with "totals", however that one should be the variable that is the total cart value after discounts. I've also tried "get_cart_total()", but that didn't help. [I've also looked at this, but don't get why replacing WC() for $woocommerce should help.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799774/woocommerce-woocommerce-check-cart-items-and-cart-total)

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out replacing

```
WC()->cart->get_cart_total();
```

with

```
$woocommerce->cart->total;
```

actually does the trick. But I don't understand why. :-D